# How to find whether traffic is in given path or not using google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
geocomplete = "<?php echo $source ?>";
autocomplete = "<?php echo $destination ?>";

var request = {
    origin: geocomplete,
    destination: autocomplete,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    provideRouteAlternatives: true,
};

directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        if (true) {
            size = result.routes.length;
            for (i = 0; i < result.routes.length; i++) {
                //   alert("Route  "+ (i+1)+"  is  "+result.routes[i].summary); 
                summary[i] = result.routes[i].summary;
                distance[i] = result.routes[i].legs[0].distance.text;
                duration[i] = result.routes[i].legs[0].duration.text;



            };
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code I can  get the distance ,time and summary for given route using Google maps API ,  i need to check whether is there any traffic in given route? how to traffic details? i do not want whole traffic details . i just wanted to know . Traffic is there or not like Boolean option. Thanks in advance

Comment: tell me errors or mistakes , do not down vote unnecessarily please

Comment: where did you read about a `traffic`-property of a `route`? You could also call `result.routes[i].makeCoffee()` but you wouldn't get a coffee.

Comment: Yes i know @Dr,Molle i read about durationInTraffic but i do not know how to use it. can you help me ? i dont get any examples also for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests)

> `durationInTraffic` (optional) specifies whether the `DirectionsLeg` result should include a duration that takes into account current traffic conditions. This feature is **only available for Google Maps API for Work customers**. The time in current traffic will only be returned if traffic information is available in the requested area.

You also have the [Traffic Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#TrafficLayer) but there is no documented method to retrieve detailed information.